# Mysql disable auto_increment column temporary in Stored procedure

Tags: mysql

In sql server there is a something like

IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF  and we can set in ON after

I wanna know is that something similar in mysql where i need to temporary set off and set ON i.e like

```
create procedure ()

    begin   
      IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF
      Some insert statement
      Some insert statement
      IDENTITY_INSERT is set to ON 
    end
```

Comment: How would you determine the value of the otherwise auto increment fields in the records inserted in your stored procedure?

Comment: The reason for this is i am using transaction for Insert statement. But when the exception occur it rollbacks the query. The next time when the insert operation is successful the auto increment column sequence is not maintain so i need to temporary disable autoincrement column in that transaction(Stored procedure)

Comment: I still can't get why do you need to switch anything off. if you know `id` you want to insert you can even if it is "ON".http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fbe5f/1

Comment: Why is it a problem if you have gaps in an auto increment field's values? Auto_increment is to provide an automated solution to generate **unique** ids. It was never meant to provide continuous numbering.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote, downvote, accept any answers with the Green checkmark whose ever it is if appropriate. That is our feedback for our efforts. We are happy to delete answers if ignore.

Comment: The one reason I have seen this done is to keep two tables ID's the same so that they can be used as a link between them instead of using a bridging table.  Ugly and when it goes wrong (and it will) much data massaging is needed to get things in sync again.  It's easy to say "it's bad design" or "use a bridging table" etc. but sometimes you have to work with what's already in place.

Answer (score 7):

I can't imagine any good reason why you need to switch that off.

If you need to insert any record with your custom `id` `AUTO_INCREMENT` is not a barrier.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4d413/1

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY (id));

INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (23);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (null);
```

So why do you need to switch it off?

Comment: This is common when developing a database script for another environment and moving those updates to staging or production via database scripts.  For example, you create a normalized Address table and Types table with rows containing the names To, From, CC, and BBC.  Your Address table with fields EmailAddress and a TypeId field that is a foreign key to the ID field in you Types table.  You have an enumeration object in your web code that sets IDs for To, From, CC, and BCC and you need the IDs to remain the same in the database.  You need to specify the IDs in your script.

Comment: @sondlerd As I explained in my answer. You can _*specify the IDs*_ without disabling auto_increment feature. So what is your point?

Comment: Using DataTables and DataAdapters, the DataAdapters even if you have the Primary Key column data in the table, the .Update() will create new primary keys for the table when it inserts them.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that you can not turn it off in some suspended mode. The best you can do is wedge data into gaps. Do so at your own peril.

Setting the auto_increment may or may not work. See the below, which in part was shown to another answerer here in a picture in a comment. Sometimes it just ignores the command to reset the auto_increment number (in his answer). In particular, it does so to protect you from faulty calls.

```
create table table1
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    type int not null,
    salary int not null
)engine=innodb;
insert table1(type,salary) values (1,99000),(1,40000),(2,49000);
select * from table1;
-- we now have 3 rows, id's 1 to 3

show create table table1; -- shows AI=4 for next one
ALTER TABLE `table1` AUTO_INCREMENT = 2; 
show create table table1; -- above does nothing, AI still equal to 4
insert table1(type,salary) values (1,50000); -- inserts it at id 4 
show create table table1;   -- shows AI=5 for next one

-- ok move it forward (create a gap) ... note, we currently have 4 rows
ALTER TABLE `table1` AUTO_INCREMENT = 8;
show create table table1;   -- confirm it. Yes, it accepted your change
insert table1(type,salary) values (1,33000); -- inserts it at id 8
select * from table1;   -- we now have 1 2 3 4 8

ALTER TABLE `table1` AUTO_INCREMENT = 5; -- move it back as you say
show create table table1;   -- confirm it (it fails to move it back) AI=9

-- it fails to let you move it back as you say (AI=9)
-- why you would want to move it back, who knows.

insert table1(id,type,salary) values (5,1,31123);
-- inserts it at id 5 (sure, no problem, in the gap)

select * from table1;
show create table table1;   -- AI for next one is still 9
insert table1(id,type,salary) values (5,1,39999); -- fails of course
```

In short don't mess with auto_increments with wise-guy code. Often it ends up wrong, is a waste of time, and is a sign of OCD thought patterns.

Comment: To complement your answer, [15.6.5 AUTO_INCREMENT Handling in InnoDB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html).

Comment: The fact that you cannot reduce the auto_increment below the existing max value in the column is documented behaviour (see MySQL documentation on alter table) and makes perfect sense. Such change would lead to duplicate keys. So, it is not  wrong behaviour. However, if a transaction inserting into the table with auto inc field is rolled back, the then the auto increment counter is increased, but the value is not present in the table. Theoretically you could reset the auto increment back to the existing max value +1 in this case. But in a multi user environment this is asking for trouble.

Comment: @shadow and the AI is known to create gaps even when FK inserts fail. Many of us have written a bit to other ops about why over thinking this and fixing gap problems that really aren't problems (but innodb protection) *features* shall we say ... well all of that effort is foolish.

Comment: As I pointed out in another comment to the answer, auto increment field is designed to provide a system generated unique identifier. It was never meant to guarantee that there will be no gaps in the sequence. What we need to establish if the OP is afraid that gaps in sequence may cause some issues with the data, or just wants a pretty sequence of numbers, or has a true need for  sequential id. For example, in Hungary the invoices must have a strict sequential numbering. No gap is allowed. Unfortunately, OP has not responded to my question regarding this.

Comment: Which is a different question