# Resetting AUTO_INCREMENT before each Arquillian test

Tags: java, mysql, jboss-arquillian

I have an Entity which has a mysql-column defined as auto_increment

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "integer auto_increment")
private int entityNumber;
```

I also have an Arquillian Test in which I test the creation and deletion of this entity. The test class is annotated using

```
@UsingDataSet("datasets/empty.xml")
```

In the code below I explain what is happening and the error I get

```
@Test
public void createEntityTest1() {
    Entity entity1 = persistEntity();
    assertEquals(1, entity1.entityNumber); // works perfectly    
}

@Test
public void createEntityTest2() {
    Entity entity2 = persistEntity();
    assertEquals(1, entity2.entityNumber); 
    // fails! Since I am in a new test I expect the new entityNumber to be 1 
    // but it is actually 2 because entity2 was previously created in 
    // createEntityTest1, although the entity itself doens't exist anymore 
    //in the DB
}
```

The problem is that after each test, the auto_increment index is not being reset, so that it keeps increasing for all my tests and when I want to check it, the auto generated numbers are greater than expected.

Is there a way to reset this value after each test?

EDIT

The sql schema of my table. It is really an easy one

```
CREATE TABLE `entity` (
  `id` varchar(36) NOT NULL
  `version` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `entity_number` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_entity_number` (`entity_number`),
  KEY `IX_entity_entity_number` (`entity_number`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Check out my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37684606) ... tldr: you can wedge in gaps, or you can set it higher. Otherwise, truncate and back to 1 for next first one. Note, with innodb and cascade deletes, you can have the db on its own clean up the parent / child FK dependencies if that is your issue in reading your question. Clean up meaning "not orphan" child rows.

Comment: It seems to be a way to do it, but I didn't want to mesh directly with mysql sentences. I was wondering if there is an "arquillian way" to do this...

Comment: you don't even have a schema here to know what the question/challenge is.

Comment: Great. If you show the mysql schema's related, and what you want them set to, I could provide a stored proc you could call like `call xyz();` as a java query. Certainly non-arquillian but a way. So, `show create table abc` for each table abc related to this whole thing.

Comment: @Drew I edited the question again. The table is pretty easy as you can see

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE `entity` (
  `id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `version` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `entity_number` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_entity_number` (`entity_number`),
  KEY `IX_entity_entity_number` (`entity_number`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- truncate table entity;

insert entity (id,version) values (8,111),(9,11111);
select * from entity;
+----+---------+---------------+
| id | version | entity_number |
+----+---------+---------------+
| 8  |     111 |             1 |
| 9  |   11111 |             2 |
+----+---------+---------------+
```

**Visual of an Alter:**

```
ALTER TABLE `entity` AUTO_INCREMENT = 550; -- move it up high
insert entity (id,version) values (700,222233333111);

+-----+--------------+---------------+
| id  | version      | entity_number |
+-----+--------------+---------------+
| 700 | 222233333111 |           550 |
| 8   |          111 |             1 |
| 9   |        11111 |             2 |
+-----+--------------+---------------+
```

**Reset to empty:**

```
truncate table entity;
insert entity (id,version) values (88888,111),(999999,11111);
+--------+---------+---------------+
| id     | version | entity_number |
+--------+---------+---------------+
| 88888  |     111 |             1 |
| 999999 |   11111 |             2 |
+--------+---------+---------------+
```

so you need to decide which of those you want to perform: [`ALTER TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html) or [`TRUNCATE TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/truncate-table.html).

But as I showed in the other [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37684606) of mine, you can use ALTER to fill known gaps if you explicitly pass the column for the auto_increment column. But you cannot move the AI value lower, not pass the AI column, and expect a gap to be filled (in that case the max(id) will auto fill the AI value to be the highest in the table).

Comment: This actually works well. For doing it in Arquillian you will need to do something like this `entityManager.createNativeQuery("ALTER TABLE `entity` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1").executeUpdate();`. Anyway I would like to know if there is an "arquillian-way" to do it before accepting this a a valid answer

Comment: Cool. I hope you can get some better answer or do a self-answer and accept that one. Cheers.