# How to make loops in MySQL to set column as manual increment?

Tags: java, php, mysql

I have an SQL database and would like to know how loops can be created in phpMyAdmin. I want to set the first column of my table as manual incremented. By this I mean I want to run a loop through all the rows which will set the integer value in the first column. It will set the numbers to: 1, 2, 3, 4, ... **I don't want to set the column to `auto_increment`**, because the counter for `auto_increment` doesn't reuse previous numbers.

I am making a Java program which will `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` from the table. I have a Swing class with buttons for each of these 3 queries. I want to execute that loop each time I press any of these buttons. So every time I press any of these buttons, the SQL loop will run and it will set all the values in the first column to 1, 2, 3, 4, ... regardless of the data in the rest of the table.

It should overwrite any data values that may already be there (just in case). So this means that each time I press the buttons, it will run the loop from the start, even though some of the numbers may have already been in order.

I am guessing I will need to put this in the `ActionListener` for each button. This is so that when the button is clicked, it can run. I also need to know how I will use the `.executeQuery("theSQLLoopGoesHere");`. The problem I can think of right now is, since the SQL loop will be have blocks of code, how would I put this in between two speech marks?

I am using MAMP 3 with "Client API library version 5.5.49".

Comment: phpmyadmin is a management interface for mysql. it is not a database, and you don't "create loops" in it. you write sql, which goes to mysql to be executed. phpmyadmin is just a middleman to handle input and display results. and why don't you want an auto_increment? that does exactly what you want.

Comment: Gaps in an incrementing numeric column are normal and trying to fill in every single value is an effort in futility. auto_increment really is the logical choice here.

Comment: @MarcB so if is there no way I can run loops? I don't want to use the auto_increment because it leaves gaps when we `DELETE` and then `INSERT`. I don't want these gaps because I need to use the command: `WHERE id = '2'`. But if I run this query, and the record with id = 2 had previously been deleted, the next record would have been id =3. There would be no record where the id was 2. I want some code that I can run through sql each time I run the `INSERT` command so that after being inserted, the loop sets the id column to increasing numbers.

Comment: @SeanLange My database and the tables are relatively small. I can afford to lose efficiency of time because my tables won't have more than about 50 rows. Is there a way to fill-in values in each row?

Comment: you should NOT be re-using ID values. if you need to figure out the next id, accounting for gaps, then use something like `select ... where id > $last_used_id order by id desc limit 1`

Comment: It isn't about efficiency it is about being concerned about gaps in a list of basically random numbers. What is the point of making sure you have ID 5 after it was deleted at some point? This is one of those things that some people get concerned with. It is not a big deal unless there is a viable business reason (In 20+ years I have not yet seen a viable reason). Just allow the gaps and keep it simple.

Comment: @SeanLange I keep having to explain why I need it to fill the gaps, here it is again: I have buttons, one button for each row in the database table, which are used for `UPDATE` . So each button is set to `UPDATE WHERE id = 2`. So if the second row doesn't have id = 2, it won't work. And instead, my button to update `WHERE id = 3` will update the second row of my table. That is why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you want [`truncate table`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/truncate-table.html). Who knows what exactly you want. As for gaps, they are your friends if they occur due to a looping mechanism due to a range allocation in that innodb engine. If the gaps occur otherwise (from deletes) that is good too for like a dozen reasons. The first one that comes to mind is Referential Integrity.

So, if you want it fresh with no data at the start, then truncate table clobbers everything and resets the AI value back to 1 for you. So the next time you insert, you are at 1. So, maybe because you say "overwrite anything if it is there" you mean you don't care about your prior data to begin with upon re-looping. Or, alternatively, maybe you mean for the prior data to be retained if not touched (you touch 1, 3, and 9).

Note that for parent tables in an FK relationship, the parent table cannot have `truncate table` run against it. The equivalent to make it work would be would be:

```
delete from myTableA;
alter table myTableA AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

The above with FK's would, of course, suggest that no child table rows would have the constraint violated by doing so.

Another unloved answer of mine about it is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37684606). Shoot the messenger perhaps.

Comment: I think I haven't explained my problem properly. I don't need to overwrite the data in the entire table, just for specific rows. I am trying to use the `UPDATE` function but if I use `WHERE id = '2'` Then if I have deleted the record with id 2, then there will be an error because id 2 doesn't exist now that it has been deleted.

Comment: That is why I want to be able manually set all the rows in the `id` column to be set through a loop, starting from 1, all the way to the largest number based on the number of rows.

Comment: Ok, then don't use auto_increment and do [IODKU](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) with the key being a primary key, or a unique key at least. Do you want me to write one for you? If so, pop on by the [Campaigns](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95290/campaigns) chat room